# sys.stdout.flush() doesn't work properly within loop in python

Tags: python, stdout, flush

I have this code:

```
sys.stdout.write("\r [*] Serching for "+FirstName+" AND "+LastName )
sys.stdout.flush()
```

But when I put it in loop, step by step I have mixture of **FirstName**s with each other and also **LastName**s with each other.

```
Searching for TEST_THREE AND EXAMPLE_THREE   #First time
Searching for TEST_TWOEE AND EXAMPLE_TWOEE   #Next time
```

You see there is `EE` of `THREE` after `TWO`...

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pad the string with extra spaces. For example, using [`str.ljust`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.ljust):

```
msg = "[*] Serching for {} AND {}".format(first_name, last_name)
sys.stdout.write("\r " + msg.ljust(70))
sys.stdout.flush()
```

using [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format):

```
msg = "[*] Serching for {} AND {}".format(first_name, last_name)
sys.stdout.write("\r {:<70}".format(msg))
sys.stdout.flush()
```

Comment: Pardon but I have the ERRO: `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'foramt'`